# How can I spec out an authlogic sessions controller using using a stub?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, authlogic

I want to test my User Session Controller testing that a user session is first built then saved. My UserSession class looks like this:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
end
```

The create method of my UserSessionsController looks like this:

```
def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    if @user_session.save
        flash[:notice] = "Successfully logged in."
        redirect_back_or_default administer_home_page_url
    else
        render :new
    end
end
```

and my controller spec looks like this:

```
describe UserSessionsController do

    it "should build a new user session" do
        UserSession.stub!(:new).with(:email, :password)
        UserSession.should_receive(:new).with(:email => "some_email@gmail.com", :password => "foobar")
        post :create, :user_session => { :email => "some_email@gmail.com", :password => "foobar" }
    end
end
```

I stub out the new method but I still get the following error when I run the test:

```
Spec::Mocks::MockExpectationError in 'UserSessionsController should build a new user session'
<UserSession (class)> received :new with unexpected arguments
  expected: ({:password=>"foobar", :email=>"some_email@gmail.com"})
       got: ({:priority_record=>nil}, nil)
```

It's although the new method is being called on UserSession before my controller code is getting called. Calling activate_authlogic makes no difference.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar problem, but I get:

Spec::Mocks::MockExpectationError in 'UserSessionsController POST 'create' when not logged in should start a new user session'
<UserSession (class)> received :new with unexpected arguments
  expected: ({:password=>"test", :login=>"quentin"})
       got: ([{:priority_record=>nil}, nil], [{:priority_record=>nil}, nil], [{"login"=>"quentin", "password"=>"test"}])

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I was getting extra :new messages on UserSession with ({:priority_record=>nil}, nil)

```
UserSession.should_receive(:new).at_least(1).times.with({ :email => "some_email@gmail.com", :password => "foobar" })
```